# What do the names Oholah and Oholibah mean in Ezekiel 23?

Tags: hebrew, ezekiel, onomastics

Ezekiel 23:4 introduces the sisters who “play the whore” in an allegory narrated by the LORD:

> ...וּשְׁמוֹתָ֗ן אָהֳלָ֤ה הַגְּדוֹלָה֙ וְאָהֳלִיבָ֣ה אֲחוֹתָ֔הּ
> <sub>([BHS](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/biblia-hebraica-stuttgartensia-bhs/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/26/230001/239999/ch/4c2a79e6e439db5b2d3ea2d188808d0e/))</sub> : וּשְׁמוֹתָ֕ן שֹׁמְר֣וֹן אָהֳלָ֔ה וִירוּשָׁלִַ֖ם אָהֳלִיבָֽה
>
> Oholah was the name of the elder and Oholibah the name of her sister....
> As for their names, Oholah is Samaria, and Oholibah is Jerusalem. <sub>([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Ezekiel%2B23/))</sub>

In addition to the fact that most names in the Hebrew Bible seem to have significance, the fact that the allegory is so transparent in its symbolism and that the two names are clearly related to one another makes it seem (to me) like the names themselves should mean something particular to the reader. The part they share is appears to be from  אֹהֶל, *ōhel*, meaning `tent`. Understanding the rest as possessive suffixes and a word division in the latter gives `Oholah = her tent` and `Oholibah = my tent [is] in her`.  Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oholah_and_Oholibah) sees this translation and asserts that the names are puns. However, the article doesn’t really explain how the pun works.

What is the meaning of these names, and what does it have to do with the allegory of Samaria and Jerusalem?

Comment: I see the ESVSB states: "The significance of the symbolism of these names has been largely lost, and the translations suggested here are approximate." Oh well! (FWIW) Still worth nudging away at.

Comment: Yes, *thank you*. The discrepancy between that and a google search which quickly reveals that many think this is indeed knowable is what got me wondering. Perhaps different styles of scholarship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As OP notes, the names "Oholah" and "Oholibah" in [Ezekiel 23:4](http://www.tanach.us/Tanach.xml?Ezek23:4-23:4) are identified as the capitals of the Northern Kingdom of Israel (Samaria) and the Southern Kingdom of Judah (Jerusalem) respectively. Typically commentators associate these obviously symbolic names with the Hebrew *ʾōhel* "tent".

**The Hebrew Names**

Again as noted by OP, these names are typically glossed this way:

- אָהֳלָה *ʾohŏlâ* = "Her [own] tent"
- אָהֳלִיבָה *ʾohŏlîbâ* = "My tent [is] in her"

Support for this understanding is found in other "ʾohel" names, e.g. Oholiab ([Exodus 31:6](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=local%3Aeng-NASB1995&v1=EX31_6&w2=bible&t2=local%3Aheb_wlc&v2=EX31_7)) or Oholibamah ([Genesis 36:2,5,etc.](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=local%3Aeng-NASB1995&v1=GN36_2&w2=bible&t2=local%3Aheb_wlc&v2=GN36_1)), although the derivation of the latter in particular has been disputed. Further support for this understanding of Oholibah has been found in "Hephzi-bah" = חֶפְצִי־בָהּ in [Isaiah 62:4](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=local%3Aeng-NASB1995&v1=IS62_4&w2=bible&t2=local%3Aheb_wlc&v2=IS62_4) (cf. 2 Kings 21:1).

There are problems here.

- The endings of the names in Ezekiel are *not* the 3rd feminine single form as expected, and as seen in "Hephzibah". This suffix should have a dot in the *he*, known as "[mappiq](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius'_Hebrew_Grammar/14._Mapp%C3%AEq_and_R%C4%81ph%C3%A8)",<sup>1</sup> which retains the consonantal value for the letter in this context. It is present in "Hephzibah", but not in either "Oholah" or "Oholibah". I.e., the "her" element, so key to the names as typically glossed, strictly isn't there.
- (To anticipate, below) *if* the names refer to shrines, then "Jerusalem" is not fitting, as the Temple is not referred to as a "tent".
- The *ʾaleph-he-lamed* cluster is sometimes associated with Phoenician or Arabic evidence to suggest associations different from "tent".

**Modern Commentary**<sup>2</sup>

Commentators generally agree that the names as such do not convey something inherently negative or judgmental, so that their significance must be sought elsewhere. Commentators still record and discuss the main options for interpreting the symbolic value of these names. The contenders include:

- the unauthorized sanctuary of the North ("her *own* tent") and the authorized sanctuary of the South ("*my* tent is in her") (Greenberg, p. 474);
- an allusion to the nomadism of the patriarchal period (Allen, p. 48);
- the names simply have a "matching quality" (Allen, p. 48, who suggests an analogy in "Tweedledum and Tweedledee"(!); Wevers, p. 134);
- the reference to "tent" in both may contain an allusion to the bridal/nuptial tent (Allen, p. 48; Block, p. 735; Zimmerli, p. 484);
- they may be simply artificial constructs, matching the syllable pattern of their "target": Shomron (Samaria)/Oh(o)lah<sup>3</sup> and Yerushalem / Oh(o)libah, with "tent" recalling the desert wanderings as a time of unfaithfulness (Block, p. 735-6);
- the names may be "foreign sounding" (connecting to the Phoenician quality of the names) emphasizing their external origins (cf. [Ezekiel 16:3](http://biblewebapp.com/study/?w1=bible&t1=local%3Aeng-NASB1995&v1=EK16_3&w2=bible&t2=local%3Aheb_wlc&v2=EK16_3); Zimmerli, p. 484).

**Assessment**

All of these commentators offer these suggestions tentatively, and usually only to reject them or shrug their shoulders in bewilderment -- except to affirm that the similarity of the names is of chief significance: these sisters are *like* each other.<sup>4</sup>

Beyond this, Robert Jenson -- in his "theological" commentary (p. 190) -- well captures the conundrum of the names:

> Presumably the sisters' names in the allegory, Oholah and Oholibah, had some significance but we lack the key...

---

*Notes*

1. See the Q&A on the possibility of the ["divine name" in Song of Songs](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/12949/2215) for another context in which the presence/absence of the *mappiq* plays a role.
2. For this answer the the following commentaries have been consulted:

   - L.C. Allen, *Ezekiel 20-48* (WBC; Word, 1990)
   - D.I. Block, *The Book of Ezekiel, Chapters 1-24* (NICOT; Eerdmans, 1997)
   - M. Greenberg, *Ezekiel 21-37*, (AB; Doubleday, 1997)
   - R.W. Jenson, *Ezekiel* (Brazos, 2009)
   - J.W. Wevers, *Ezekiel* (NCB; Oliphants, 1969)
   - W. Zimmerli, *Ezekiel 1* (Hermeneia; Fortress, 1979)
3. The short "o" in *ʾoh**ŏ**lâ* is a semi-vowel. (I'm just reporting here, not commending!)
4. Thus Block, p. 736: "In the last analysis, it is not their meaning that is most significant but their similarity. ... [T]hese names match, highlighting the women's sibling relationship". Cf. Zimmerli, p. 484; further, Amy Kalmanofsky, "[The dangerous sisters of Jeremiah and Ezekiel](http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/journal_of_biblical_literature/v130/130.2.kalmanofsky.html)", *Journal of Biblical Literature*, 130/2 (2011): 299-312 (who is interested in the *siblings*, not at all in the symbolic value of the names).

Comment: Could you gloss אהליאב  (FYI link goes to 31:7) and/or אהליבמה ? (And yes, I looked, and no, it’s not in my ESVSB.) Also, if Oh(o)libah then I suppose Y(e)rushalem? (Not really sure what to do with the last syllable(s) as written there though. Is there both a *patach* and a *hiriq* under the *lamed*? As if לַיִם- ?)

Comment: Maybe: Oholiab = "the father is my tent" (*'ab* as "divine" father?)? Oholibamah = "my tent is with them"? *ABD* has brief discussions of both. | (Link target differs in different browsers, it seems.) | The "semi-vowel" can be included or ignored at one's convenience. :) | And yes, typically two vowels for the one consonant: probably *[qere perpetuum](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/9173/)* - cf. GKC [88c](https://goo.gl/B5xIWw) and [17c](https://goo.gl/0w3KOa).

Comment: Thank you. ([ABD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_but_dissertation)?) | (Link target differs possibly because the URL specifies v.6 for NASB and v.7 for WLC.) | Well if *qere* = יְרֽוּשָׁלַ֫יִם‎ then we have to ignore the shwa there but count it (er...something vaguely like it) in the “analogous" Oh**o**libah.  (“Not commending”, I know I know...)

Comment: *ABD* = *[Anchor Bible Dictionary](http://yalepress.yale.edu/yupbooks/SeriesPage.asp?Series=145)*. (Sorry about that!) | (Might have been, but doesn't matter whether the last digit is "6" or "7" - I think it has to do with how BibleWebApp manages its sync'ed auto-scrolling.) (That's my story and I'm sticking to it!)

Answer (score 1):

### Analogy of Oholah and Oholibah

There is some disagreement as to the actual significance of the meaning of the names but there is no disagreement as to the fact that they to be understood figuratively. Rashi, commenting on this passage calls them "nicknames".

He further states,

> *Samaria is the one I nickname Oholah, for from the beginning she
>   became a tent (אֹהֶל) for the calves of Jeroboam and for Ahab’s temple
>   of Baal. Although Samaria was not built until the days of Omri, He
>   calls the kings of Israel by its name, because as soon as it was
>   built, it became the capital.*(Taken from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16121#showrashi=true))

It is with her sister(Oholibah), that there is some disagreement. He states,

> *Oholibah: Because My tent (אֹהֹלִי) was in her (בָה), and My sanctuary*

In Keil and Delitzsch's Commentary on the same passage, they challenge the conclusion that some have in regarding this meaning:

> *The name אהליבה is formed from אהלי בהּ, "my tent in her;" and,
>   accordingly, אהלה is to be derived from אהלהּ, "her tent," and not to
>   be regarded as an abbreviation of אהלהּ בהּ, "her tent in her," as
>   Hitzig and Kliefoth maintain. There is no ground for this assumption,
>   as "her tent," in contrast with "my tent in her," expresses the
>   thought with sufficient clearness, that she had a tent of her own, and
>   the place where her tent was does not come into consideration.*(Taken from [here](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/kad/ezekiel/23.htm))

The names that they are representing of course are **שֹׁמְר֣וֹן**(Samaria), which is derived from **שָׁמַר**(shamar-to keep watch), and **וִירוּשָׁלִַ֖ם**(Jerusalem), (place of peace). An interesting sidenote is that "Bethel"(House of God) was located at one time in both Ephraim(Samaria) and Benjamin, where Jacob had received his vision. The fact the Temple was in Jerusalem was to be in no way misunderstood as God's presense was only in Jerusalem, "Bethel" was the place that Israel anointed and paid his tithes to, where "The house of God" and the "gateway to heaven" was revealed to him.(Gen. 28:17)

To further expound on this imagey of 'tents', when Jacob returned with his 2 wives, Leah and Rachel, they dwelt in tents near Shalem which was in Shechem.
**שָׁלֵם**(shalem) of course is "complete" or "whole"-a derivative word is shalom, which means peace. **שכם**(Shechem) means "shoulder" in the masculine; but it means "to rise early" in it's feminine form. Isn't it a coincidence that Samaria(shamar) was to "rise up early to shoulder" or watch it's "peace"(shalem/shalom)?

I believe it's also no accident that Rachel 'stole' her father Laban's idols(Gen. 31:34), the consequence of the nation of Israel having "idols" hidden in the tent, which certainly follows Ezekiel's analogy.

The rest of the passage illustrates in graphic detail what these sister's sins were, which compared to the sins of Israel(Samaria) and Judah in their allegiences and pursuit of the Assyrian, Babylonian, and Syrian empires, in complete rejection of God's protection and provision for them. They adopted the practices and idolatry of these nations and became as bad or worse than the nations around them. The graphic sexual imagery is analgous to the way that a jealous husband (God), sees an unfaithful wife who is persistant in exploiting her unfaithfulness. The judgments He spells out for them will for all time settle the matter of idolatry for them.

### Summary

Though there appears no actual 'play' on words "Ohola" and "Oholibah" that I have been able to find in my research, there is considerable comparison to Jacob's wives, who were 'tents' for their children to dwell in "peace and watchfulness". But because of idolatry, they left their "place of security" and "played the harlot" to the nations which surrounded them. God's impending judgment towards them was that He would tolerate it no longer, but would thoroughly purge them from this sin.

.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the names
Oholah and Oholibah

What do the names Oholah and Oholibah mean in Ezekiel 23?

---

And what does it have to do with the allegory of Samaria and Jerusalem?

---

Answer :
It describes the state of human beings as a Whole Humanhood; it does explain the possible outcome that any human being can get at by either going on a Spiritual Journey or not?
Free choice is there all the time; and, we see with the two sisters names two aspects of : DOING AS PER THE BEING WHICH IS IN THE NAME!
In an ancient hebrew mind, a name was describing a character of an individual and the behaviour of what it meant; doing is being and being is doing!
My answer is based on gematria and also the meanings that I did get from the roots that are part of each name.

אהלה
אהליבה

The two names are very similar in meanings; but the one name which is said to be the older daughter seems to have less Awareness because the added letters ( יב ) can tell us what the difference is!
Here is the Whole Picture pertaining to both names :
GEMATRIA :
[image: Gematria]

- בא
  to enter; to lead to, to bear.
  [www.billheidrick.com/works/hgm1.htm](http://www.billheidrick.com/works/hgm1.htm)
  ** יב
  ‫יבב‬
  To wail, whine, whimper, lament, complain, sob, ululate.
  ‫בוא‬
  ‫יבא‬
  To come, arrive, enter, go/lead in, bring, come to pass ►import ►get "turned on", be successful/unsuccessful ►have no desire ►arrive at by chance ►set (sun).
  איב
  To be hostile to/an enemy of ►show enmity.
  SHOROSHIM THE ULTIMATE AND UNIQUE ENGLISH THESAURUS OF HEBREW VERB ROOTS COMPILED BY REUVEN BRAUNER (2014).

---

432=2x2x2x2x3x3x3;
בכית weeping.
בלת lack, nothing.
בתל to separate, seclude.
כבדות heaviness; difficulty.
בנפש at cost or risk of life.
432
[www.billheidrick.com/works/hgm3.htm](http://www.billheidrick.com/works/hgm3.htm)
Note : בנפש awareness of the spirit Within!
About added letters ( יב )
[image]
Note : using the Albam Chart (The Albam Chart is the Aleph Beith that was apparently used by the creator in order to make this world), we can get a more real meaning of what the difference is :
יב becomes : שם
Conclusion :
The difference has something to do with the name; since the parabole is given by Hashem, we can say that the whole story is an allusion to the fact that the provider of : ALL THERE IS … is wanting us to become our Name!
https://www.kabbale.eu/guematria-temourah-et-notariqon/

Now using gematria pertaining to : Chapter 23 and counting the verses involved, we get : 23+49 = 72; which is The Fourth Sephirah Chesed on the Tree of Life. We are here facing the grace and mercy of the Provider of : ALL THERE IS! Taking this into consideration can help us interstand the meanings of names and what is asked of the bearer of the Name that we Have!
72
חסד
to bow, bend (the neck) ; to incline oneself; to be gracious, pious; to abuse, insult; kindness, goodwill, compassion; piety, religion; mercy, favor; reproach, disgrace; pr.n. "Chesed" --- the name of the fourth Sephira, considered masculine and active in traditional Qabalah. Chesed is (911) in Greek 16 . It corresponds 17 to the
Right Arm of Adam Qadmon (161) . (The adverse meanings may come from use in irony) .
[www.billheidrick.com/works/hgm1.htm](http://www.billheidrick.com/works/hgm1.htm)

---

Answer to the second part of the Question :

And what does it have to do with the allegory of Samaria and Jerusalem?

Answer :
It is about the fact that at start a human being in general has a great potential to become more Aware of his or her Spiritual Nature, but, there is this fact that as time go by, we go on a Spiritual Journey if we so desire?
Hence, the two names describes two stages in the process of becoming Aware, and, in a similar manner, Samaria and Jerusalem do have different approach to becoming on a Journey of Becoming more Aware of the Beyond the physical only reality!

Samaria>

https://www.abarim-publications.com/Meaning/Samaria.html

שמרון
Place Of Watching.
to guard or to exercise great care over.

Jerusalem>

https://www.abarim-publications.com/Meaning/Jerusalem.html

ירושלם
ירושלים
bringing about of a unified effect by means of many little impulses.
Possession Of Peace.

Overall conclusion :
We are here reading a story that could enable our gain of Awareness; we could ignore the fact that we can be careful and be watchful. Thus, most of the verses are narrating the decline of the situation when some human being is not re-adjusting and do see to his or her own interest first.

Answer (score 0):

What do the names Oholah and Oholibah mean in Ezekiel 23?
Answer :
WE ARE ALL MESSIACHS!
AND WHEN WE CAN UNITE OUR TWO NATURES, WE ARE BECOMING ONE!

Oholah
אהלה
Note : the construct of the first mentioned name of the older daughter is very similar to the construct of : YHVH; we have the two Hey, the Aleph that starts the name has the same simple gematria value of the Yud, and the Lamed is by it’s graphy (shape of the letter), it is a Waw (Vav) and a Kaf. The Kaf together with the Lamed makes the word for : Whole. Hence, we can say that this name is an allusion to YHVH with the Kaf for a meaning of ‘’your’’ or ‘’you’’ as for : your Provider of ALL THERE IS!
כל
50
[www.billheidrick.com/works/hgm1.htm](http://www.billheidrick.com/works/hgm1.htm)
completeness, totality, all; the whole; every; any one; wholly; altogether.

Oholibah
אהליבה
Note : the construct of the second name of the younger daughter is similar to the other name Oholah, but the added יב is giving us a clue that we are dealing with the vessel that contains the Yud; Yud being the reduced allusion of : YHVH, Beith being the house of YHVH. Hence, we can say that the human being is this existential being that enables a soul to be incarnated and here existing; it is also the allusion to the עבד , an allusion to the suffering servant.
https://www.abarim-publications.com/Dictionary/ay/ay-b-d.html

---

And what does it have to do with the allegory of Samaria and Jerusalem?

Answer :
The allegory is an allusion to the two schools of thoughts that are there existing : Elohimism and Yahwism; and, because Elohim and Yahweh are One, we can expect that the messianic era is there when Unity is there!

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is an answer that is more intuitive and yet more Real I would suggest; in Numbers 10, verses: 35 and 36, we have one word that is without any of the letters found in the Tetrammaton YHVH, it is the second word used in verse number : 35.
בנסע
Answer based on this word in relation to : Oholah and Oholibah:
The two names are two aspects of the hidden Reality that is Spiritual, but that does need a process of truth seeking in order to get on a Spiritual Journey that will enable Enlightment!
For more details on this see my draft of my first book (sypnosis): Beingness is a big business in a nutshell!
Link:
https://www.academia.edu/77723639/Beingness_is_Big_Business_in_a_nutshell_8_Glorian
Conclusion: when we get more Aware of the Spiritual Reality, we get on a journey that brings us closer to : Enlightment; but, we need to seek Truth by finding a way to go across the many tests and barriers that our existence does throw at us!
Glorian

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).