# What is the meaning and function of הַהִוא֒ in Exodus 3:8?

Tags: hebrew, exodus, grammar

I'm translating Exodus 3:8, but I'm a bit stumped on the meaning and function of the following word:

## הַהִוא֒

> ## וָאֵרֵ֞ד לְהַצִּיל֣וֹ ׀ מִיַּ֣ד מִצְרַ֗יִם וּֽלְהַעֲלֹתוֹ֮ מִן־הָאָ֣רֶץ הַהִוא֒ אֶל־אֶ֤רֶץ טוֹבָה֙ וּרְחָבָ֔ה אֶל־אֶ֛רֶץ זָבַ֥ת חָלָ֖ב וּדְבָ֑שׁ אֶל־מְק֤וֹם הַֽכְּנַעֲנִי֙ וְהַ֣חִתִּ֔י וְהָֽאֱמֹרִי֙ וְהַפְּרִזִּ֔י וְהַחִוִּ֖י וְהַיְבוּסִֽי׃
>
> And I go down to deliver them from the hand of Egypt, and to cause them to go up from the land **[ ??? ]** to a land good and broad, to a land flowing with milk and honey, to the place of the Canaanite, and the Hittite, and the Amorite, and the Perizzite, and the Hivite, and the Jebusite.
>
> (Exodus 3:8)

My best guess is that it's a demonstrative adjective, in which case it should be "to cause them to go up from **that** land". Although that's not how the YLT chooses to translate it.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Possibly related: '[What does “Qr perpetuum” mean?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/9173/2215)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your know this is the 3rd person, feminine, singular pronoun הִוא with the article .  BDB defines this usage as "that."  See below.

> 7. With the art. הַהוּא, הַהִיא, הָהֵ֫מָּה, הָהֵם, הָהֵ֫נָּה: so regularly when joined to a subst. defined itself by the art.: Gn 2:12 הָאָרֶץ הַהִוא that land, 19:35 ובלילה ההוא and in that night, 21:22 בָּעֵת הַהִוא at that time, Dt 1:19 המדבר הגדול והנורא ההוא. Only four times does there occur the anomalous construction בַּלַּיְלָה הוּא Gn 19:33; 30:16; 32:23; 1 S 19:10.

Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 216). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

Note that this is how most translations, including the LXX translate this word in Exodus 3:8.

In HALOT, it is: "10. hahûʾ, hahîʾ w. nouns, that (adj.), hāʾîš hahûʾ Jb 1:1;..."

Holladay, W. L., & Köhler, L. (2000). A concise Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament (p. 77). Leiden: Brill.

Comment: [הוא] is 3rd P singular masculine indicative. Not feminine.

Comment: @Cynthia With the waw you would think so, but the MT vowel points have it as hi instead of hu.

Comment: @Cynthia How are you getting indicative for a pronoun?

Comment: @PerryWebb Re: "`...but the MT vowel points have it as hi instead of hu.`" See the Q&A linked under the question. It is a complex form.

Comment: Btw, the chart [here](https://hebrew4christians.com/Grammar/Unit_Six/Demonstrative_Pronouns/demonstrative_pronouns.html) is a good summary of the whole demonstrative pronoun paradigm. Also re @Dɑvïd's last point, you'll find quite a number of 3fs pronouns written with the consonants for *hu* but pointed for *hi* in the Pentateuch. My old BH professor said it was a likely relic of a more ancient form.

Comment: A good way to remember the 3rd person pronouns from the standpoint of pronunciation is the following: who (hu) is he, he (hi) is she, and she (shi) is it.